# Filter and drop rows by proportion python

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe called wine that contains a bunch of rows I need to drop.

How do i drop all rows in column 'country' that are less than 1% of the whole?

Here are the proportions:

```
#proportion of wine countries in the data set
wine.country.value_counts() / len(wine.country)

US                        0.382384
France                    0.153514
Italy                     0.100118
Spain                     0.070780
Portugal                  0.062186
Chile                     0.056742
Argentina                 0.042835
Austria                   0.034767
Germany                   0.028928
Australia                 0.021434
South Africa              0.010233
New Zealand               0.009069
Israel                    0.006133
Greece                    0.004493
Canada                    0.002526
Hungary                   0.001755
Romania                   0.001558
```

...
I got lazy and didn't include all of the results, but i think you catch my drift. I need to drop all rows with proportions less than .01

Here is the head of my dataframe:

```
country designation points  price   province    taster_name     variety     year    price_category
Portugal  Avidagos   87     15.0    Douro       Roger Voss  Portuguese Red  2011.0  low
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
country_filter = wine.country.value_counts(normalize=True) > 0.01
country_index = country_filter[country_filter.values == True].index
wine = wine[wine.country.isin(list(country_index))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
df = df[df.proportion >= .01]
```

From that dataset it should give you something like this:

```
US                        0.382384
France                    0.153514
Italy                     0.100118
Spain                     0.070780
Portugal                  0.062186
Chile                     0.056742
Argentina                 0.042835
Austria                   0.034767
Germany                   0.028928
Australia                 0.021434
South Africa              0.010233
```

Comment: Thanks, Jab. Do i need to import anything to use .proportion?

Comment: Well you never gave the names of the columns so I assumed the second column was proportion.

Comment: ah i see, I added the other columns